# Не загружаются файлы в цикле

Tags: файлы, php, циклы

Загружается только один файл

---

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $i++){
                    $do_file = false;
                    // Проверка загрузки с обычного браузера
                    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] > 0) {
                        $do_file = true;
                        $ifname = strtolower($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]);
                        $rand = rand(111111, 999999);//случайное число
                        $fname = ''.$rand.'_'.$ifname;
                        $fsize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
                    }
                    //обработка файла
                    if ($do_file) {            
                        // Список допустимых расширений файлов.
                        $al_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp');
                        $ext = explode(".", $fname);
                        // Проверка на допустимый размер файла
                        if ($fsize >=$setup['filesize_kartinka'])
                        {
                        echo "<script> alert('Файл должен быть меньше ".size($setup['filesize_kartinka'])." !'); document.location.href='';</script>";
                        exit;
                        }
                        }
if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$i], "../files/backgammon/images/".$fname."")) == true) {   
img_resize('../files/backgammon/images/'.$fname.'', '../files/backgammon/images/min_'.$fname.'', 224, 212);  
img_resize('../files/backgammon/images/'.$fname.'', '../files/backgammon/images/small_'.$fname.'', 116, 76);
img_resize('../files/backgammon/images/'.$fname.'', '../files/backgammon/images/view_'.$fname.'', 640, 480); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `auction_image` SET `id_auction` = '".$fidd."', `file` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($fname)."'");  
    }
    }
```

---

```
echo '<div class="addcomment"><form action="auction.php?backgammon&amp;add" method='.htmlspecialchars("post").' enctype="multipart/form-data">';
echo '<p><b>Продолжительность аукциона:</b><br/><input type="datetime-local" id="comment" size="142" name="time" value="'.$_POST['time'].'" required></p>';
echo '<p><b>Title:</b><br/><textarea id="comment" rows="1" cols="142" name="title" required>'.$_POST['title'].'</textarea></p>';
echo '<p><b>Description:</b><br/><textarea id="comment" rows="1" cols="142" name="description" required>'.$_POST['description'].'</textarea></p>';
echo '<p><b>Начальная цена:</b><br/><textarea id="comment" rows="1" cols="142" name="ncena" required>'.$_POST['ncena'].'</textarea></p>';
echo '<p><b>Минимальный шаг:</b><br/><textarea id="comment" rows="1" cols="142" name="minshag" required>'.$_POST['minshag'].'</textarea></p>';
echo '<p><b>Блиц-цена:</b><br/><textarea id="comment" rows="1" cols="142" name="blic" required>'.$_POST['blic'].'</textarea></p>';
echo '<p><b>Выберите изображения:</b> <br/><input type="file" name="userfile[]" required/> ';
?> 
<a href onclick="append('test'); return false;" title="Нажмите для добавления файла">[+]</a>
<?
                echo '<div id="test"></div>';
echo '</p>';
echo '<p><b>Выберите видео-файл:</b> <br/><input type="file" name="video"/></p>';
echo '<p><b>Содержание:</b><br/><textarea id="texttext" name="text">'.$_POST['text'].'</textarea></p>';
echo '<div style="text-align:left"><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Добавить лот"/></div></form></div>';
```

Кто-нибудь подскажет, в чем проблема?

Comment: Загружается только 1 файл, но теряется формат. С виду все правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Предоставьте html код формы, которая посылает запрос на обработку в PHP

И ещё. `echo "<script> alert('Файл должен быть меньше ".size($setup['filesize_kartinka'])." !'); document.location.href='';</script>";
                        exit;
    **exit** - делает остановку выполнения скрипта, используйте **break** - для выхода из цикла, либо **continue** - для пропуска

Comment: Добавил в первое сообщение.
Ок.

Comment: Видать никто не знает ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить

`echo '<div id="test"></div>';`

На

`echo '<div id="test"><input type="file" name="userfile[]" required/></div>';`

Ещё попробуйте вывести массив $_FILES после отправки формы. Какой вид имеет массив?

Comment: Перед формой у меня код


<script>
function append(id) {
    var node = document.getElementById(id),
        newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML = '<?echo '<p><input type="file" name="userfile[]"></p>';?>';
    node.appendChild(newNode);
    return newNode;
}  
</script>

Comment: Никто не подскажет? Так то вроде код правильный.

Comment: vitagame, попробуйте вывести массив $_FILES после отправки формы. Какой вид имеет массив?

Comment: Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => Array [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/jpeg [2] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpN0xuHQ [1] => /tmp/php12pcuD [2] => /tmp/phpfn5fhq ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 845941 [1] => 595284 [2] => 775702 ) ) [video] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )